# image src is not loaded when loading a component

Tags: node.js, angular

I use multer file uploader in to upload files into a storage folder which is under assets folder. It seems to be the file will be uploaded but it is not loaded to localhost/assets/storage which is shown in sources of the web page

used enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: We need a code.
You really think we can guess what you wrote?!

Comment: I think i found the error. Any recommendations to build a folder dynamically when the browser refreshed?